# wild card distribution provision profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am trying to build two different ipa files for the same app using two different signatures, so it can be installed on a device consequently for testing purpose. I am not sure if its possible to have a wild card for distribution provision profile? Can anyone guide me as of how to possibly have same kind of apps tested on a device with different signature?

Thanks

Comment: You need to create separate Distribution profile for each app identifier.

Comment: do you mean, you want to create a separate distribution profile for each device, and you want xcode to do it for you?

Comment: calvin, you got that right.. Is that even possible?